# Constraint on a three dimensional rotation to preserve vector length

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given

$\begin{bmatrix}
\bar{A}^{x}\\ 
\bar{A}_{y}\\ 
\bar{A}_{z}
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
R_{xx} & R_{xy} &R_{xz} \\ 
R_{yz} &R_{yy}  &R_{yz} \\ 
R_{zx} &R_{zy}  &R_{zz} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{x}\\ 
A_{y}\\ 
A_{z}
\end{bmatrix}$

What constraints must the element $R_{ij}$ of the three dimensional rotation matrix satisfy in order to preserve the length of **A** for all vectors **A**

A crucial hint would be very helpful. **No answers**!

Comment: By definition a rotation matrix is a unitary matrix, so if shouldn't modify the norm.

Comment: Presumably you know rotation matrices preserve length, so strictly speaking, there are no constraints beyond the fact that the $R_{ij}$ are elements of the rotation matrix. But perhaps you're looking for a characterization of rotation matrices. For this, note that the length of $\mathbf{a}$ is $\sqrt{\mathbf{a^Ta}}$. So you want $(R\mathbf{a})^T(R\mathbf{a})=\mathbf{a^Ta}$ for all $\mathbf{a}$. Simplify the left-hand side to deduce something about the matrix $R$.

Comment: Only half of length-preserving transformations are called rotations. For example, reflection with respect to a plane or a point preserves the lengths of vectors, but wouldn't be called a rotation, since it reverses orientation. So you need to specify whether you want to keep those kinds of transformations.

Answer (score 4):

The question is a bit confusing because a "rotation" matrix is one that performs rotation, and rotations don't change lengths. So, the answer to your question is that there are **no** constraints -- because **every** rotation matrix preserves lengths. Incidentally, all reflection matrices preserve lengths, too.

But, I suspect that what you really want to know is what constraints on a $3\times 3$ matrix cause it to preserve lengths.

Providing a good hint is harder than providing the answer, but here's an attempt ...

If the matrix $\mathbf{R}$ preserves lengths, then $\|\mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}\| = \|\mathbf{x}\|$ in the particular case where $\mathbf{x} = (0,0,1)$. So, specifically, when  $\mathbf{x} = (0,0,1)$, we have $\|\mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}\| = 1$, and this tells you that 
$$
R_{xx}^2 + R_{yx}^2 + R_{zx}^2  = 1
$$
If we let $\mathbf{u} = (R_{xx}, R_{yx}, R_{zx})$ denote the first column of $\mathbf{R}$, this says that $\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{u} = 1$. If we let $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ denote the second and third columns, then you can probably figure out how to show that $\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v} = 1$ and $\mathbf{w} \cdot \mathbf{w} = 1$, by similar reasoning.

Next, try to figure out the values of $\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{w} \cdot \mathbf{u}$.

Eventually, you'll find that the three vectors $\mathbf{u}$, $\mathbf{v}$, $\mathbf{w}$ have some very special relationship with each other, which is one way to express the constraint you're after.

Next, observe that
$$
\mathbf{R}\mathbf{R}^T =
\left| \; 
\begin{matrix}
\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{u} & 
\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} & 
\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{w} \\
\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{u} & 
\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v} & 
\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{w} \\
\mathbf{w} \cdot \mathbf{u} & 
\mathbf{w} \cdot \mathbf{v} & 
\mathbf{w} \cdot \mathbf{w} \\
\end{matrix} \;
\right|
$$
So, once you have the values of all those dot products, you'll see that $\mathbf{R}\mathbf{R}^T = \text{<something special>}$, which is another way to state the constraint.

This is all somewhat circuitous, but that's because I'm trying to lead you in circles around the answer, rather than directly to it, since this seems to be what you want.

You can get the answer much more directly by magical manipulation of symbols, if you want: just follow the hint given in the comment by @symplectomorphic.

Comment: Can we say that the columns of the matrix $R$ must be orthonormal?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.